# How to delete and merge outgoing relationships on the same query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using cypher. I am trying to delete all out going relationships before creating new ones on the same query. 
i have weird situation if the relations/nodes already existed it's working as expected. if They never been created before I get:

```
(no changes, no rows)
```

This is my query:

```
match (user{userId:'a'})-[r:nearby_wifi]->() delete r 
MERGE (p1:BT{userId:'a'}) WITH p1, [{bssid:"0a:18:d6:c1:3d:fd",level:"-51",timestamp:"1973-08-27 02:26:35.423",venueName:""},{bssid:"04:18:d6:c2:3e:2a",level:"-55",timestamp:"1973-08-27 02:26:35.425",venueName:""},{bssid:"0e:18:d6:c1:3d:fd",level:"-53",timestamp:"1973-08-25 11:06:07.392",venueName:""}] AS wifis 
UNWIND wifis AS wifi 
MERGE (p2:WIFI{bssid: wifi.bssid}) 
MERGE (p1)-[r1:nearby_wifi]->(p2) 
SET r1.dist=wifi.dist 
SET p1.lastTimeActive=1460378030215
SET p2.level=wifi.level 
SET p2.timestamp=wifi.timestamp 
SET p2.venueName=wifi.venueName
```

Any idea why when combining delete and the merge executions I got no changes(when graph empty)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace first `match` with `optional match`

For example if you have no client nodes in your database, but have some person nodes query

```
Match (p:Client) with p Match (r:Person) return *
```

will get nothing, but query

```
Optional Match (p:Client) with p Match (r:Person) return *
```

will give you Persons. I think neo4j optimizer stops executing query after it gets no results and with `optional match` it gets null, and continues executing.

Comment: Optional match did the trick. but i am not sure I understand why. why when graph is empty optional match will let me execute second query?

Comment: I'm afraid my knowlage isn't deep enough to answer this question.  I found out it by practice and assumed that if some query returns nothing (not null, null is something) it doesn't continue to execute, but I really never looked for this fiture explonation in documentation.